# jquery selector including parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with 3 select lists, I'm using the jquery multipleSelect addon to select lists using checkboxes, I want to be able to select all selections from a specific group, I can do this for everything on the page using:

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]')
```

Can I select all checkboxes from a group by including the id of the parent node?

I'm open to other methods of achieving the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do,

```
 $('.parentclassname input[type=checkbox]')
```

Or

```
 $('#parentId input[type=checkbox]')
```

Or

```
$(parentselector).find('input[type=checkbox]')
```